# Use of shared memory to reduce computational time of calculations inside CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have an image of size 1920 x 1080. I am transferring from H2D, processing and transferring back from D2H using three CUDA streams where each stream is responsible to take care of 1/3rd of total data. I am able to optimize the dimensions of block and number of threads per block by understanding the concept of SM, SP, warps. The code run satisfactorily (takes 2 ms) if it has to do simple calculations inside kernel. The **simple calculation code** below find the R, G and B value from source image and then place those values in the same source image.

```
ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 0] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 0];
ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 1] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 1];
ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 2] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 2];
```

But I have to perform **few more calculations** which are independent of all other threads then, the computational time gets increased by 6 ms which is too much for my application. I have already tried to declare the mostly used constant values inside the `constant memory`. The code for these calculation is shown below. In that code, I am again finding the  R, G and B values. Then, I am calculating new values of R, G and B by multiplying the old values with some constants and finally I am putting these new R, G and B values again in the same source image at their corresponding positions.

```
__constant__ int iw = 1080;
__constant__ int ih = 1920;
__constant__ int numChannels = 3;


__global__ void cudaKernel(unsigned char *ptr_source, int numCudaStreams)
{

    // Calculate our pixel's location
    int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

    // Operate only if we are in the correct boundaries
    if (x >= 0 && x < iw && y >= 0 && y < ih / numCudaStreams)
    {

        const int index_b = numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 0;
        const int index_g = numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 1;
        const int index_r = numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 2;

        //GET VALUES: get the R,G and B values from Source image
        unsigned char b_val = ptr_source[index_b];
        unsigned char g_val = ptr_source[index_g];
        unsigned char r_val = ptr_source[index_r];

        float float_r_val = ((1.574090) * (float)r_val + (0.088825) * (float)g_val + (-0.1909)  * (float)b_val);
        float float_g_val = ((-0.344198) * (float)r_val + (1.579802) * (float)g_val + (-1.677604)  * (float)b_val);
        float float_b_val = ((-1.012951) * (float)r_val + (-1.781485) * (float)g_val + (2.404436)  * (float)b_val);


        unsigned char dst_r_val = (float_r_val > 255.0f) ? 255 : static_cast<unsigned char>(float_r_val);
        unsigned char dst_g_val = (float_g_val > 255.0f) ? 255 : static_cast<unsigned char>(float_g_val);
        unsigned char dst_b_val = (float_b_val > 255.0f) ? 255 : static_cast<unsigned char>(float_b_val);

        //PUT VALUES---put the new calculated values of R,G and B
        ptr_source[index_b] = dst_b_val;
        ptr_source[index_g] = dst_g_val;
        ptr_source[index_r] = dst_r_val;

    }
}
```

**Problem:**  I think that transferring the image segment (i.e. `ptr_src`) to the shared memory will help but I am quite confused about how to do it. I mean, the scope of shared memory is for one block only so, how do I manage the transfer of image segment to the shared memory.

**PS:** My GPU is Quadro K2000, compute 3.0, 2 SM, 192 SP per SM.

Comment: We are missing some details of your implementation. Do you use three streams and then divide each color channel among the streams? In addition, you wont get any performance improvement by using shared memory in this example as all operations are done at pixel level. In fact, it would be possible that the _always hungry for optimizations_ nvcc compiler will move the computations to registers. As a final note your memory access pattern to global memory is not coalesct because consecutive threads do not access consecutive memory positions.

Comment: @pQB: I have updated the second sentence of my question. Hope, now I am able to clarify the use of 3 streams.

Comment: I'm not sure if you will get any benefit for splitting the image among three streams. Why dont let the blocks in the `y` dimension do all the work? Despite that, the comment about the shared memory remains the same, as well as the problems with coalescing. Those improvement (coalescing) will probably gives you a lower execution time.

Comment: @pQB: Three streams have definitely benefited me because of parallel data transfer and kernel execution. I did not understand your sentence `memory access pattern to global memory is not coalesct because consecutive threads do not access consecutive memory positions.` because  I am not too much familiar with this stuff.

Comment: You do realize that you have double precision arithmetic in this kernel and could get a free two times speedup without changing a line of your code (Other than fixing the double precision constants)....

Comment: @talonmies: that was the first thing I tried but believe me, it did not make any change.

Comment: @skm: I don't believe you. Because whenI benchmarked your kernel on a compute 2.1 device, there was a 2x speed up just by fixing that. And I confirmed that the compiler was emitting double precision instructions for those operands

Comment: @talonmies: whether you believe it or not but at least at my system, it did not improve the computational time. I checked the time using `nvvp` in milliseconds up to 3 decimal digits. PS: my device is of Compute 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared memory won't help for your case, your memory accesses are not coaslescent.

You can try the following : replace your char* ptr_source into a uchar3* should probably helps your threads accessing contiguous datas in your array.
uchar3 just means : 3 contiguous unsigned char.

since threads within a same warp execute same instruction at the same time you'll have this kind of access pattern :

Supposing you try to access memory at adress : 0x3F0000.

```
thread 1 copies data at : 0x3F0000 then 0x3F0001 then 0x3F0002

thread 2 copies data at : 0x3F0003 then 0x3F0004 then 0x3F0005
```

0x3F0000 and 0x3F0003 are not contiguous, so you'll have bad performance accessing to you datas.

with uchar3 uses :

```
thread 1 : 0x3F0000 to 0x3F0002

thread 2 : 0x3F0003 to 0x3F0005
```

like each thread copies continous datas your memory controller can copy it quickly.

You can too replace :

```
(float_r_val > 255.0f) ? 255 : static_cast<unsigned char>(float_r_val);
```

with

```
float_r_val = fmin(255.0f, float_r_val);
```

this should give you a kernel like this :

```
__global__ void cudaKernel(uchar3 *ptr_source, int numCudaStreams)
{

    // Calculate our pixel's location
    int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

    // Operate only if we are in the correct boundaries
    if (x >= 0 && x < iw && y >= 0 && y < ih / numCudaStreams)
    {
        const int index =   (iw*y + x);

        uchar3 val = ptr_source)[index];

        float float_r_val = ((1.574090f) * (float)val.x + (0.088825f) * (float)val.y + (-0.1909f)  * (float)b_val.z);
        float float_g_val = ((-0.344198f) * (float)val.x + (1.579802f) * (float)val.y + (-1.677604f)  * (float)b_val.z);
        float float_b_val = ((-1.012951f) * (float)val.x + (-1.781485f) * (float)val.y + (2.404436f)  * (float)b_val.z);

        ptr_source[index] = make_uchar3( fmin(255.0f, float_r_val), fmin(255.0f, float_g_val), fmin(255.0f, float_b_val) );
    }
}
```

i hope these update will improve performance.

Comment: the use of `uchar3` has made me confused about the `cudaMemcpy()`. I am using three streams. `numTripleBytes = image.rows * image.cols;`,  `totalMemSize = numTripleBytes * sizeof(uchar3);` and memory segment for each stream is `memSegmentSize = totalMemSize / 3`. Now, the call `cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src[j], h_src + (j*memSegmentSize), memSegmentSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[j]);` has some problem. `j` varies from 0 to 2 because I have 3 streams.

Comment: What do you mean by "has some problems". Actually the `totalMemSize` should be the same as before since `sizeof(uchar3) == 3*sizeof(unsigned char)`

Comment: Normally you should just cast your unsigned char* to uchar3* within your kernel call.

i've update my post to try to explain what is coesleced access

Comment: @X3liF: ok, I will check with it tomorrow and will then update the scenario.

Comment: @X3liF: Why bother with a 2D indexing scheme at all? It is completely unnecessary and the indexing overhead is a considerable fraction of the total compute load.

Comment: @X3liF: the use of `uchar3` is creating some problem. I am getting an error `an illegal memory access was encountered ` for the line  `cudaStreamSynchronize(stream[i])`. I tried to do something very simple to become sure. If I make the changes in the image at kernel using `val.x = 0; val.y = 0; val.z = 255 and ptr_source[index] = val; ` then, I get the above mentioned error whereas if I use my previous method i.e. `ptr_source[index + 0] = 0; ptr_source[index + 1] = 0; ptr_source[index + 2] = 255;` then it displays the expected RED image.

Comment: @talonmis thanks for this advice, i'll think about this next time

Comment: @skm i've not tested this kernel, but this behaviour should not happen, have you divided "iw" by 3 when computing your boundaries ?

Comment: @X3liF: yes...all the things were same.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add this code without too much comment for the moment:

```
const int iw = 1080;
const int ih = 1920;
const int numChannels = 3;

__global__ void cudaKernel3(unsigned char *ptr_source, int n)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    uchar3 * p = reinterpret_cast<uchar3 *>(ptr_source);

    for(; idx < n; idx+=stride) {

        uchar3 vin = p[idx];
        unsigned char b_val = vin.x;
        unsigned char g_val = vin.y;
        unsigned char r_val = vin.z;

        float float_r_val = ((1.574090f) * (float)r_val + (0.088825f) * (float)g_val + (-0.1909f)  * (float)b_val);
        float float_g_val = ((-0.344198f) * (float)r_val + (1.579802f) * (float)g_val + (-1.677604f)  * (float)b_val);
        float float_b_val = ((-1.012951f) * (float)r_val + (-1.781485f) * (float)g_val + (2.404436f)  * (float)b_val);

        uchar3 vout;
        vout.x = (unsigned char)fminf(255.f, float_r_val);
        vout.y = (unsigned char)fminf(255.f, float_g_val);
        vout.z = (unsigned char)fminf(255.f, float_b_val);

        p[idx] = vout;
    }
}

// Original kernel with a bit of template magic to conditionally correct
// accidental double precision arithmetic removed for brevity

int main()
{
    const size_t sz = iw * ih * numChannels;
    typedef unsigned char uchar;
    uchar * image = new uchar[sz];

    uchar v = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        image[i] = v;
        v = (++v > 128) ? 0 : v;
    }

    uchar * image_;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&image_, sz);
    cudaMemcpy(image_, image, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 blocksz(32,32);
    dim3 gridsz(1+iw/blocksz.x, 1+ih/blocksz.y);
    cudaKernel<1><<<gridsz, blocksz>>>(image_, 1);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(image_, image, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaKernel<0><<<gridsz, blocksz>>>(image_, 1);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(image_, image, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaKernel3<<<16, 512>>>(image_, iw * ih);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

The idea here is to just have as many threads as can be resident on the device, and have them process the whole image, with each thread emitting multiple outputs. Block scheduling is very cheap in CUDA, but it isn't free, and neither are indexing calculations and all the other "setup" code required for one thread to do useful work. So the idea is simply to amortise those costs over many ouputs. Because your image is just linear memory and the operations you perform on each entry are completely independent, there is no point in using a 2D grid and 2D indexing. It is simply additional setup code which slows down the code. You will also see the use of a vector type (char3) which should improve memory throughput by reducing the number of memory transcations per pixel.

Also note that on double precision capable GPUs, double precision constants will be compiled and produce 64 bit floating point arithmetic. There is a 2 to 12 times performance penalty when performing double precision compared to single precision depending on your GPU. When I compile the kernel you posted and look at the PTX the CUDA 7 release compiler emits for the sm_30 architecture (the same as your GPU), I see this in the pixel computation code:

```
cvt.f64.f32     %fd1, %f4;
mul.f64         %fd2, %fd1, 0d3FF92F78FEEF5EC8;
ld.global.u8    %rs9, [%rd1+1];
cvt.rn.f32.u16  %f5, %rs9;
cvt.f64.f32     %fd3, %f5;
fma.rn.f64      %fd4, %fd3, 0d3FB6BD3C36113405, %fd2;
ld.global.u8    %rs10, [%rd1];
cvt.rn.f32.u16  %f6, %rs10;
cvt.f64.f32     %fd5, %f6;
fma.rn.f64      %fd6, %fd5, 0dBFC86F694467381D, %fd4;
cvt.rn.f32.f64  %f1, %fd6;
mul.f64         %fd7, %fd1, 0dBFD607570C564F98;
fma.rn.f64      %fd8, %fd3, 0d3FF946DE76427C7C, %fd7;
fma.rn.f64      %fd9, %fd5, 0dBFFAD7774ABA3876, %fd8;
cvt.rn.f32.f64  %f2, %fd9;
mul.f64         %fd10, %fd1, 0dBFF0350C1B97353B;
fma.rn.f64      %fd11, %fd3, 0dBFFC80F66A550870, %fd10;
fma.rn.f64      %fd12, %fd5, 0d40033C48F10A99B7, %fd11;
cvt.rn.f32.f64  %f3, %fd12;
```

Note there is promotion of everything to 64 bit floating point, and the multiplications are all done in 64 bit, with the floating point constants in IEEE754 double format, and the results are then demoted back to 32 bit. This is a real performance cost and you should be careful to avoid it by properly defined floating point constants as single precision.

When run on a GT620M (a 2 SM Fermi mobile part, running on batteries), we get the following profile data from nvprof

```
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 39.44%  17.213ms         1  17.213ms  17.213ms  17.213ms  void cudaKernel<int=1>(unsigned char*, int)
 35.02%  15.284ms         3  5.0947ms  5.0290ms  5.2022ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 18.51%  8.0770ms         1  8.0770ms  8.0770ms  8.0770ms  void cudaKernel<int=0>(unsigned char*, int)
  7.03%  3.0662ms         1  3.0662ms  3.0662ms  3.0662ms  cudaKernel3(unsigned char*, int)

==5504== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 95.37%  1.01433s         1  1.01433s  1.01433s  1.01433s  cudaMalloc
  3.17%  33.672ms         3  11.224ms  4.8036ms  19.039ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize

  1.29%  13.706ms         3  4.5687ms  4.5423ms  4.5924ms  cudaMemcpy
  0.12%  1.2560ms        83  15.132us     427ns  541.81us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.03%  329.28us         3  109.76us  91.086us  139.41us  cudaLaunch
  0.02%  209.54us         1  209.54us  209.54us  209.54us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  23.520us         1  23.520us  23.520us  23.520us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  13.685us         3  4.5610us  2.9930us  7.6980us  cudaConfigureCall
  0.00%  9.4090us         6  1.5680us     428ns  3.4210us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.00%  5.1320us         2  2.5660us  2.5660us  2.5660us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  2.5660us         2  1.2830us  1.2830us  1.2830us  cuDeviceGet
```

and when run on something bigger (GTX 670 Kepler device with 7 SMX):

```
==9442== NVPROF is profiling process 9442, command: ./a.out
==9442== Profiling application: ./a.out
==9442== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 65.68%  2.6976ms         3  899.19us  784.56us  1.0829ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 20.84%  856.05us         1  856.05us  856.05us  856.05us  void cudaKernel<int=1>(unsigned char*, int)
  7.90%  324.64us         1  324.64us  324.64us  324.64us  void cudaKernel<int=0>(unsigned char*, int)
  5.58%  229.12us         1  229.12us  229.12us  229.12us  cudaKernel3(unsigned char*, int)

==9442== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 55.88%  45.443ms         1  45.443ms  45.443ms  45.443ms  cudaMalloc
 38.16%  31.038ms         1  31.038ms  31.038ms  31.038ms  cudaDeviceReset
  3.55%  2.8842ms         3  961.40us  812.99us  1.1982ms  cudaMemcpy
  1.92%  1.5652ms         3  521.72us  294.16us  882.27us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
  0.32%  262.49us        83  3.1620us     150ns  110.94us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.09%  74.253us         3  24.751us  15.575us  41.784us  cudaLaunch
  0.03%  22.568us         1  22.568us  22.568us  22.568us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.03%  20.815us         1  20.815us  20.815us  20.815us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.01%  7.3900us         6  1.2310us     200ns  5.3890us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.00%  3.6510us         2  1.8250us     674ns  2.9770us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  3.1440us         3  1.0480us     516ns  1.9410us  cudaConfigureCall
  0.00%  2.1600us         2  1.0800us     985ns  1.1750us  cuDeviceGet
```

So there is *big* speed up to be had just by fixing elementary mistakes and using sensible design patterns on both smaller and larger devices. Believe it, or not.

Comment: the use of `uchar3` is creating some problem. I am getting an error  `an illegal memory access was encountered` for the line `cudaStreamSynchronize(stream[i])`. I tried to do something very simple to become sure. If I make the changes in the image at kernel using `p[index].x = 0;  p[index].y = 0;  p[index].z = 255;` then, I get the above mentioned error whereas if I use my previous method i.e. `ptr_source[index + 0] = 0; ptr_source[index + 1] = 0; ptr_source[index + 2] = 255;` then it displays the expected RED image.

Comment: There is no stream in your code but as I mentioned that I am using three streams in my code so, I have only changed the kernel as per your suggestion. There is no other problem in the code as it is able to work for different configurations but I get the error only when I am trying to process the image using `uchar3 *` type pointer.

Comment: How could I possibly answer you? How do I know what code you have written? The code added in this answer is intended for you to study and *understand*, not cut and paste into your codebase. It shows several important concepts (how to process multiple inputs/outputs per thread, how to use vector types to improve throughput, the perils of accidental double precision arithmetic). This isn't place a code writing or personalised help service. Questions and answers are intended to be of benefit for everyone, not just you in the here-and-now. Think about that.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand your point. I am just asking you about the changes which you have suggested. My point is only that that the use of `uchar3 *` is throwing an error in copying back the results from D2H. Whereas, the use of `unsinged char *` is not throwing any error. So, may be there is something which I need to know about the proper use of `uchar3`. Now, I cannot change my original question so, if the problem persists then, I will post a question about this problem with a minimal working example.

Comment: Again, I am not suggesting changes to your code. That isn't the point of this answer. I am demonstrating concepts which you can learn from in the form of a complete example code, and backing them up with real world profiling data.

Comment: just want to update you that if I use a 2D array instead of a real image then, `uchar3` is working in my case too. But if I use a real image (either loaded from PC or synthetic), I get an error about illegal memory access. I did not use any stream. I am posting a new question with a minimal working.

Comment: So all this line of questioning was actually the result of copying a mistake from the other answer? Did you even look at the code I wrote?

Comment: Yes, I looked at your code and read each and every sentence. You are calculating 1D index but I thought of first checking the use of `uchar3` using 2D index. It did not came into my mind that I should not use `numChannel` for `uchar3` type of pointer. I am extremely sorry for the inconvenience. I did not post the new question immediately, I tried to do several other tests but unfortunately, could not find the simple mistake.